# Is there a way to reuse the previous comment on a git commit?

Tags: git

Occasionally I will drop into troubleshooting mode and commit/push a number of small but separate commits with a comment like, "Troubleshooting the <something> during deployment to Heroku." I would like to use the same comment for each commit without having to retype it. Is this possible?

Comment: Visual Studio Code allows you to up arrow to the previous commit message(s) as of version 1.51.0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At first, I answered:

> I guess `git commit --reuse-message=HEAD` does it

Then I thought that's not what you wanted and deleted it. Then life caught up and got AFK for a couple of hours. Anyways, despite an answer having already been accepted, I would have suggested:

```
$ git config alias.troubleshoot '!troubleshoot() { git add -u && git commit -m "Troubleshooting the $1 during deployment to Heroku."; }; troubleshoot'
```

And you use it the following way:

1. modify existing files
2. (eventually add untracked files)
3. `git troubleshoot foo`

Would commit changes (and eventually new files) with "Troubleshooting the **foo** during deployment to Heroku." as commit message.

Comment: This is a safer solution to the problem, and it is also a solution for the broader problem, How do I easily reuse common git commit comments? The fact that you can use parameters helps ensure that the log doesn't get filled up with useless comments, too. See [Aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) for more information.

Answer (score 44):

From the [git-commit(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) command documentation,

```
-C <commit>
--reuse-message=<commit>
Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship 
information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.

-c <commit>
--reedit-message=<commit>
Like -C, but with -c the editor is invoked, so that the user can further edit 
the commit message.
```

It's then possible using,

```
  git commit --reuse-message=HEAD
```

**Update:**

You may also need to use the `--reset-author` option,

```
--reset-author
When used with -C/-c/--amend options, declare that the authorship of the 
resulting commit now belongs of the committer. This also renews the author 
timestamp.
```

Comment: Ah, so this isn't pulling from MY most recent commit comment?

Comment: Thinking this over... If I type `git commit -a --reuse-message=HEAD` locally, how could it pull anything other than my most recent commit comment? How would another team member's comment sneak in there with that command and context?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, Yes, it's pulling from your most recent commit message according to where your HEAD is pointing to. 
If you've another comment interfering between the new one and the last one, it will then take this comment's message.

Comment: You can use a given commit hash as value to the --reuse-message option. Ancestors to HEAD are also reachable.

Answer (score 14):

.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG contains the last commit message. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_files

```
git commit --file .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

will use that file as the commit message.

Comment: Additionally pass `--edit` if you want to be able to modify the commit message.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of how you can have a certain set of git commits use the last git comment you had entered, but you *can* set a default commit message. That could do the trick as long as you unset the default commit message once you're done with all the commits that needed to use that message.

Here's how you go about setting a default commit message. First, enter the desired commit message in a file, lets call it `~/LastCommitMessage.txt`. Then, specify this as your default (global) commit message like so:

```
$ git config --global commit.template ~/LastCommitMessage.txt
```

You could narrow the scope by not using --global and using something else instead.

You can easily access all git settings by opening up the `.gitconfig` file located in your home directory. Open up that file and delete the setting above to unset it once you're done with all your commits.