# Git: How to reuse commit message (both subject and description)

Tags: git, commit, reusability, commit-message

How to reuse past commit's message while pushing new commit to the branch so that both subject **and** the description are retained?
When I am typing
`git commit --reuse-message=<commit_ID || commit_ref>`
or
`git commit --reedit-message=<commit_ID || commit_ref>`
, whether I'd like to just copy-paste the message or edit it first, I am getting the message subject only.
Any suggestions? In advance, thx!

Comment: `whether I'd like to just copy-paste the message or edit it first, I am getting the message subject only.` ? What you mean by this  ?

Comment: What is the difference between the "subject" and "description" of a commit message?  From Git's point of view, the commit message is a single logical thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to reuse the previous comment on a git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429086/is-there-a-way-to-reuse-the-previous-comment-on-a-git-commit)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, subject is first line and description is remainder

Comment: Turns out that commands that I provided above indeed fetch the whole message of the indicated commit.
Consequently, the question duplicates the one linked by @stud3nt

Thank you all for the help. Greetings!